# Simple example where Bayesian > Frequentist (Unambiguously)?

Tags: bayesian, frequentist

I'm trying to understand the main appeal of Bayesian methods & whether they are indeed capable of offering more than regular frequentist methods. The thing is my impression is that by default the prior should be 'uninformative' (i.e. Objective Bayesian movement). And I've heard doing this gives you similar results to frequentist?

But I've also heard that Bayesian can be more sample efficient? Is this true? For example if you have a large prior sample (say a control group's data accumulated across several different research projects), but a small experimental group say <= 100 samples.
Does bayesian handle inference in this situation better than frequentist somehow?

P.S. Specifics given in the body of my post are context. But question remains what is in the title.

Comment: If you're forcing the jumping-off points to be as similar as possible ([uninformative priors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/57117), same likelihood, etc.) then [MLE and Bayesian (point) estimates will coincide](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/57257). But the benefits of Bayesian methods go beyond that: what's most attractive about Bayesian inference is that it gives direct answers to scientific questions, rather than [indirect and convoluted ones](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3194022).

Comment: @Durden So are you advocating the use of informative priors? (e.g. a prior based on some theory). Or are emphasizing that the bayesian uncertainty distribution is the "more direct answer" to 'which hypothesis is correct'?

Comment: If you have the information, you should use it.  The whole uninformative prior thing is for situations, which are all too frequent (see what I did there?) where your prior information is "possibly seriously biased opinion" and shouldn't be allowed to contaminate your results - or worse, "I can get any result I want by altering my prior enough" scenarios.

Comment: Personally, I'm buying into [Andrew Gelman's argument](https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2011/12/29/more-by-berger-and-me-on-weakly-informative-priors/) of having *weakly* informative priors as defaults (if any), because it avoids the problems and paradoxes that [might ensue from non-informative priors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/600000) (which are most often improper).

Comment: @Durden are you referring to e.g. the reference priors like Bernardo/Jeffery?
If so I agree, otherwise I don't know yet what you mean.

Comment: It is possible for uninformative priors to give objectively wrong results.  There was some, err "discussion" a while back on a paper that gave a very low estimate for the sensitivity of the climate to greenhouse gasses.  They used an uninformative Jeffrey's prior, which is strongly peaked at zero, a value that we objectively know (from physics) is not a plausible value for climate sensitivity, which was part of the reason for the objectively wrong low "objective" value.  "objective" is a term-of-art in this context.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial Ah yes, if a strong theory exists (e.g. especially physical/scientific), then I agree it is no longer justified to use a reference prior.
I guess I was mostly responding to what Duren meant by "paradoxes" (e.g. improper posterior).

Comment: One of the paradoxes I was mentioning is the [so-called 'marginalization paradox'](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.2517-6161.1973.tb00952.x). It causes all kinds of nasty problems [when Bayes factors are calculated with improper priors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/35789).

Comment: related https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/41394/56940

Comment: Just for completeness: another problem with uninformative priors is that they can be [vulnerable to Dutch books](https://doi.org/10.3150/bj/1099579159).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am holding a coin, of unknown bias, in my hand.  I flip it once, and it comes down heads.  A friend asks me what a fair bet would be for the next flip to be heads.

What's the frequentist point estimate of the probability that the next flip is heads?

(The answer is less obvious than it may appear, as "frequentist" does not specify the estimation procedure.)

As a Bayesian, this is straightforward.  Because a vast amount of randomness in the result is due to my erratic coin-flipping procedure and the symmetry induced by having the coin either face up or face down when flipping it, I find it extremely unlikely that a coin flip will be biased by more than 1% (49%-51%).  I put a Beta(10,000, 10,000) prior on the probability of a head, which gives me a prior mean of 50% and a prior standard deviation of 0.005.  My posterior is therefore a Beta(10,001, 10,000) distribution, and the posterior mean is 10,001 / 20,001 or 0.500025.

Edit in response to comments:

Bayesian statistics is focused on "small" samples, as asymptotically in (most) situations Bayesian and MLE results become the same.  However, in my past applied work - estimating degradation rates of solar panels based on a limited number of years of experimentation - even sample sizes of 100 (application specific) aren't as informative as you might think they would be, and prior information can really make a difference.

Also, why limit yourself to a small experimental group when you have sufficient prior information available to, indirectly, allow you to have a large experimental group?  In a way, it's the experimental group you're really interested in, after all.

Comment: I see what you mean and I agree, (P(H)=1?). I'm curious if some kind of benefit  extends to slightly larger sample sizes (e.g. n=20, H>0, T>0). 

Like is bayesian much better at incorporating a strong prior (e.g. control accumulated across many studies), vs frequentist approach of just putting large control group into 1 side of a t-test & small experimental group into the other?

Comment: I apologize tho, your answer is indeed a correct answer to my question. I just should've been more specific.

Comment: @profPlum - I've updated the answer to address your comments, somewhat.

Answer (score 5):

Just to give an example that hasn't been mentioned yet: **in logistic regression, a regularizing term based on the Jeffreys prior was shown by [Firth](https://doi.org/10.1093/biomet/80.1.27) to produce unambiguously better estimates (in terms of reducing both bias and variance) than vanilla MLE.** And as a cherry on top it also mitigates the [problem of perfect separation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11109) (see [Heinze and Schemper](https://doi.org/10.1002/sim.1047)). There's already [a great post explaining why it works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/88734), so I'm not going to repeat it here.

Ironically it is not commonly "advertised" as a Bayesian method, but rather a form of penalized maximum likelihood estimation.

Answer (score 4):

The frequentist definition of a probability is based on a long run frequency, the Bayesian definition is based on plausibility or state of knowledge (whether subjective or objective).  The Bayesian approach is going to be better, in the sense of being able to give a direct answer, if the question is not asking for a long run frequency (such as the probability that some proposition is true, which doesn't have a long run frequency, it is either true or it isn't).

Now frequentists can give indirect answers to questions about things like the truth of a proposition, usually by inventing some fictitious population which may have long run frequencies.  However it is an indirect answer that will often be treated as a direct answer leading to misunderstandings such as the p-value fallacy (the p-value is not the probability that the null hypothesis is true, and indeed a frequentist fundamentally cannot attach a numeric probability to that anyway!).

However, Baysian analysis often requires the ability to perform numerical integration, which most of us find tricky, whereas the frequentist framework has proven well suited to a "statistics cookbook" approach and is often used by practitioners who don't really understand the underlying principles, but can use it because it is comparatively easy to implement.  Hopefully packages such as Stan will make it easier to apply the Bayesian approach with time?  This makes it difficult to say whether a Bayesian approach is unambiguously better than a frequentist approach, because there are multiple criteria that govern which framework to use.

Horses for courses, ideally choose the framework that answers your question directly... unless it is too tricky in which case reach for the cookbook ;o)

With regards to "informative" priors, in some cases we have knowledge from e.g. physics that mean that uninformative priors are objectively (in the everyday sense of the word) implausible.  Our statistical analyses should include domain knowledge where appropriate.  The XKCD cartoon about frequentist-v-Bayesian gives a good example of what happens if we try for purely data driven inference in situations where we do have useful domain knowledge!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the caricature of the dumb frequentist. Btw, I love how you think it is difficulty with numerical integration that holds back the Bayesian approach. Perhaps you are overestimating the scientific interest in Bayesians' evaluations of their personal uncertainties.

Comment: @GrahamBornholt If you read my answer you would note that I say it is a matter of "horses for courses" - both frameworks have their uses and problems.  As it happens most practitioners of frequentist NHSTs make exactly the error that is in the cartoon - not considering prior knowledge in setting the significance level (as Fisher advocated).  I was pointing out that prior knowledge is important whether you are a Bayesian or a frequentist.  Bayesian probabilities are not necessarily personal, there is such a thing as objectivist Bayesianisn - see Janes etc.

Comment: Having taught Bayesian statistics to frequentist statistics students, I have seen their faces when you start talking about integrals on the blackboard. ;o)

Comment: The importance of scientific context for hypothesis testing has long been stressed in frequentist statistics (Cox(1958) was a great example). Sadly, most practitioners of statistics are not statisticians and this leads to the misuse of p-values, and the failure to take context into account. Statistical inference is only a part of scientific inference. That nonstatisticians misuse statistical tools does not signify a problem with the tools

Comment: Perhaps the participants in your cartoon should have been a practitioner and a statistician.

Comment: @GrahamBornholt it is a cartoon, the fact that it has a ***trace*** of truth in it is what makes it amusing.  As it happens, statisticians (including profs that teach statistics) suffer from some of the same misunderstandings, see https://www.researchgate.net/publication/241372934_The_Null_Ritual_What_You_Always_Wanted_to_Know_About_Significance_Testing_but_Were_Afraid_to_Ask particularly this bit about the survey by Haller and Kraus.  The main reason that practitioners get it wrong is that the underlying framework is very subtle and does not directly answer their question (IMHO).

Comment: The Bayesian approach often does directly answer their question (what is the probabilty that the null hypothesis is false) but it isn't well suited to a "cookbook" approach, so if you are not good at integrals, you won't find it easy to use.  At the end of the day it is horses for courses and part of the course is the expertise of the user.  As long as they are used skeptically even the null ritual is better than nothing.

Comment: Fair enough if you find the posterior probability a satisfying answer. Regarding "cookbook" methods, surely the Bayesian approach is full of cookbook methods: conjugate priors, reference priors , etc ...... However difficult integration is, students must ask themselves do we need this. The 'elephant in the room' is surely that many scientists have no interest in someone's posterior probabilities: they are more interested in modelling the data-generating mechanism itself not how my uncertainty/probability is changed by data (IMHO).

Comment: @GrahamBornholt "Fair enough if you find the posterior probability a satisfying answer." a Bayesian could equally say "If you find a procedure that doesn't actually answer the question satisfying".  Sorry, I find the frquentist/Baysian antagonism rather tiresome when taken seriously.  I made it clear in my answer that both frameworks are useful, both have advantages and disadvantages to those with an open mind about it.  " my uncertainty/probability" I have already pointed out objective Bayesianisn, so you have just shown you are ignoring what I have written.